# How does the GoogleTalk client do Off-the-Record messaging?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

The Google Talk client built into Gmail offers Off The Record messaging:

[image]

But, when I click the link to "Go off the record", it works *immediately* without any noticable steps to authenticate the other end. Pidgin and the official OTR plugin let me choose between a Fingerprint, a shared secret, and answering user-defined questions. If both users are on the Gmail Google Talk client, it won't ask for anything like that.

What does Google do to authenticate the other party?

---

I am assuming that what Google labels "go off the record" refers to the [Off-the-Record Messaging Protocol](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/Protocol-v2-3.1.0.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>It basically stops take a copy of your convosation but still does all the authentication etc</strike> Was an assumption see Google's answer :)

> 1. What does it mean to go off the record?
>
> We know that sometimes, we don't want
>   a particular chat, or chats with a
>   specific person, to be saved. Most
>   existing IM services give no
>   indication of whether the person
>   you're chatting with is saving your
>   conversation. But when chatting in
>   Google Talk or Gmail, you can go "off
>   the record," so that nothing typed
>   from that point forward gets
>   automatically saved in anyone's Gmail
>   account.
>
> Going off the record applies to
>   individual people, and is persistent
>   across chats. That means once you go
>   off the record with a particular
>   person, you will always be off the
>   record with him or her, even if you
>   close the chat window, and the two of
>   you don't chat again until several
>   months later. You will not need to go
>   off the record each time you chat with
>   the same person, but you will need to
>   make this decision for each person you
>   chat with. We've designed this to be a
>   socially-negotiated setting because we
>   want to give users full disclosure and
>   control over whether the person
>   they're talking to can save their
>   chat.
>
> To go off the record while chatting,
>   click the Options button and select
>   "Go off the record" from the dropdown
>   menu. Both people can go off the
>   record or stop chatting off the record
>   at any time, and we will always notify
>   both people of such a change.

REF [Google Talk chat history](http://www.google.com/talk/chathistory.html#offrecord)

Comment: What do you mean by "still does all the authentication etc"? This quote sounds like "off the record" merely means "disable logging", rather than **[otr](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/Protocol-v2-3.1.0.html)**. A scary thought.

Comment: @Stefano I mean that it still checks who your talking to like it normall does and I think it does literally mean it just turns off logging by "off the record"

Comment: Yeah you were spot on Matt. That's pretty awful.

Comment: @Stefano dont for get to mark as answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Just like Matt says in [his answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16931/how-does-the-googletalk-client-do-off-the-record-messaging/16932#16932), **it just turns off logging**.

I just got confirmation of this by Associate Professor Ian Goldberg, one of the authors of ["Off-the-Record Communication, or, Why Not To Use PGP"](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/~iang/pubs/otr-wpes.pdf) and lead developer of [the OTR software suite](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/people.php) (in other words: *the* guy):

> GTalk's "off the record" button indeed
>   just means that they (claim to[*])
>   stop logging your conversation.  It
>   has nothing to do with "Off-the-Record
>   Messaging" (OTR).  Google still sees
>   all of your messages in cleartext, you
>   are trusting it to correctly tell you
>   who you're talking to, etc.
>
> [*] I wonder what would happen if
>   Google received a court order to log a
>   certain party's messages, as happened
>   to Hushmail a while back.  Would that
>   checkbox disappear?  Would they just
>   ignore its setting?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's really not OTR (as in end-to-end encrypted chats).